# Wrong 2nd argument type , Found 'androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle', required 'int' Error

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, mobile, android-viewpager2

I'm getting this error when trying to implement a viewpager2

here is the relevant code:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Fragment[] childFragments;
public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
    super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);

}
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    childFragments = new Fragment[] {
            new user_fragment(), //0
            new zayyd(), //1
            new chat() //2
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `FragmentPagerAdapter` class may has only a 2 parameters constructor `FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager, int)`, so the sub class cannot `super(FragmentManager, Lifecycle)`.

You can create another constructor in FragmentPagerAdapter that accept `(FragmentManager, Lifecycle)` or create another contructor in ViewPagerAdapter that use `(FragmentManager, int)`